# MySQL is not creating the table from an imported SQL file correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, syntax, mysql-workbench

I converted a Microsoft SQL creation table syntax into MySQL and let MySQL import the SQL file, I keep getting an error. This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Adminstration (
    AdminID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ContactID int constraint fk_Admin_Contact foreign key (ContactID) references ContactInfo(ContactID),
    EEID int constraint fk_Admin_Employee foreign key (EEID) references Employees(EEID),
    LName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EContactID int constraint fk_Admin_EContact foreign key (EContactID) references EmergencyContacts(ECID),
    Position VARCHAR(50),
    DOB DATE
);
```

However, I keep getting an error saying:

> contraitnt" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting AS, AUTO_INCREMENT, CHECK< COLLATE, COLUMN_FORMAT, COMMENT...

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What have you tagged SQL Server for a MySQL question?

Comment: Maybe you have a typo error `contraitnt` ?

Comment: I recommend reading the product documentation...

Comment: There is a difference in syntax between a column constraint (such as the one you attempt to define for ContactID) and a table constraint. You used the latter syntax - which is not valid as a column constraint. By definition, a column constraint would only be associated with the column you are defining.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a small error, the constraints are not valid in the column definition that way.

```
CREATE TABLE Adminstration (
    AdminID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ContactID int,
    constraint fk_Admin_Contact foreign key (ContactID) references ContactInfo(ContactID),
    EEID int,
    constraint fk_Admin_Employee foreign key (EEID) references Employees(EEID),
    LName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EContactID int
    ,constraint fk_Admin_EContact foreign key (EContactID) references EmergencyContacts(ECID),
    Position VARCHAR(50),
    DOB DATE
);
```